# VB.NET quick Navigation to Specific Events on Double Click (During Designer Time)

Tags: vb.net

I am Currently using Visual Studio 2017 for my applications and recently made a few custom usercontrols. these usercontrols made was introduced a custom event handler.

```
Private Sub uctxtCustomer_CustomEvent() Handles uctxtCustomer.CustomEvent
    '' Code Here
End Sub
```

For example, is there any way which i can double click my user control on the form during designer which can navigate directly to the code `uctxtCustomer.CustomEvent` instead of generating a load event (`uctxtCustomer.Load`)? i could scroll slowly or use the quick event finder given on the top. but it get tedious when i have many controls and different events.

Comment: What you do is up to you but I hate Hungarian Notation so much that I feel compelled to comment. When you look at the .NET Framework, do you see any types whose begin with the likes of "uctxt"? If you give your class a proper name then you don't need silly prefixes like that. `Customer` is a name for a type that represents a `Customer`, not a control that displays customer information. I strongly suggest that you fix that name and don't use prefixes like that ever again. They were only ever intended to be used on variables anyway. Using them on types is an abomination.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I don't think that's on a type, it's on a specific instance of the control (thus, a variable).  I think there is still some utility to using prefixes on controls to get sorting by type (particularly sorting the ones with behavior out from the ones without).

Comment: @Craig, you're quite right. Not sure why I thought otherwise. Hungarian Notation on variables still sucks, but not as much as on types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the fact that your event handler has no parameters suggests that you have not implemented things correctly. To learn all the ins and outs of custom events, check [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html) out. As for your question, you need to specify the desired event as the default for the type, e.g.

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel

<DefaultEvent("SomeEvent")>
Public Class Class1

    Public Event SomeEvent As EventHandler

    '...

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you very much! i never knew this existed. also for the link. i will study it more.